# How can I add UI test screenshot to TFS Test Report as an attachment

Tags: selenium, tfs, nunit, mstest

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio Test Tools and VSTFS v.15. I managed to take screenshots using Selenium and currently store them in 'TestLogsDir' folder. When I run UI tests locally I can easily locate my screenshots after each test run. But after running nightly build on a Virtual Machine 'TestLogsDir' is being deleted. Obviously, I can store screenshots somewhere else, but the thing is how can I attach the screenshot to a corresponding test case in TFS Test Report?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the test framework you're using to run the UI tests:

- **MsTest**: [TestContext.AddResultsFile(file)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile.aspx)
- **NUnit** (3.8+): [TestContext.AddTestAttachement(file)](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1670)
- **XUnit.NET**: [Not available at the moment](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/936).

Comment: thanks! I'll try. I'm using MSTest + Selenium. Looks like it's pretty easy in your example. Does it mean that it will attach the created screenshot to TFS report in runtime depending on TestContext?

Comment: Yes, it will be saved and a link to the picture is added to the trx file. When the trx is published to TFS/VSTS, the attachments are added.

Comment: AddResultsFile is unfortunately not available in the .net core implementation of the TestContext (2.1, per 10/01/2018)

Comment: arynaq: it's available as of v2 of the MS Test Framework (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967929/where-do-i-find-testcontext-addresultfile)

Answer (score 0):

Below code, I used to take a screenshot, save it in the working directory and, update the file to TFS build.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Webdriver).GetScreenshot();

    string screenshotFile = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory, "screenshot.png");
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotFile, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

    TestContext.AddTestAttachment(screenshotFile, "Error Snapshot:");
```