# Where do I find TestContext.AddResultFile()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, mstest

I am having trouble referencing [the documented method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/collect-screenshots-and-video?view=azure-devops) `AddResultFile()` on the `TestContext` class, allegedly found in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` package/namespace.

This is my package list:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="2.46.0" />
<PackageReference Include="specflow" Version="3.0.199" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.0.199" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.MsTest" Version="3.0.199" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.0.0-beta4" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.0.0-beta4" />
```

This is (a part of) my test (step definition - it's SpecFlow) class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using XunitTestLib.Drivers;
using XunitTestLib.Helpers;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace XunitTestLib.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class BrowserSteps : BrowserDriver
    {
        public IWebElement CurrentElement { get; set; }
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        public BrowserSteps(TestContext tcontext)
        {
            this.TestContext = tcontext;
        }

        [Given(@"I navigate to (.*)")]
        [When(@"I navigate to (.*)")]
        [Then(@"I navigate to (.*)")]
        public void INavigateTo_(string url)
        {
            Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        // ***Numerous methods for specflow/selenium-based testing***

        [Given(@"I take a screenshot")]
        [When(@"I take a screenshot")]
        [Then(@"I take a screenshot")]
        public void ITakeAScreenshot()
        {
            var sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_SS_") + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            var path = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{sep}{time}.png";

            Browser
                .GetScreenshot()
                .SaveAsFile(path);

            TestContext.AddResultFile(path); // THIS METHOD NOT FOUND
        }
    }
}
```

How do I find and use the `AddResultFile()` method? I assume I'm missing a reference...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in `MSTest.TestFramework` package reported here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/394

It is resolved 4 days ago from today in a pull request :

https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/pull/609

But I can not see any update in nuget version from last 23 days for version `2.0.0-beta4` and there is no version after that right now. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/

**Intermediate fix** is to use latest bits from here **till there is new update with this fix**:

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/mstestv2/api/v3/index.json

In particular, you should update your adapter and framework nuget package to these versions:
https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/mstestv2/package/nuget/MSTest.TestAdapter/2.0.0-build-20190430-01
https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/mstestv2/package/nuget/MSTest.TestFramework/2.0.0-build-20190430-01

**Update 09/2019**: the v2 of the MS Test Framework was officially released with the method in question included.